# Hi, I created joomla component. it item load with id. how do add alias for that component.

Tags: joomla

I created joomla component. it item load with id.  how do add alias for that component.

My site url
joomla/cochrane_v3/products/clearvu-%E2%80%93-critical-infrastructure/3.html

how do i replace 3 with it alias

I created component use below site.
http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have an alias field in your database and form, then you usually generate a "slug" in your database select query like this:

```
SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END as slug
...
```

This creates something like `3:youralias` which can then be used to build the URL instead of the id. When reading the URL, you just use (int)$id to strip the part behind the ":" and get your clean id.

**Step by Step**

1. Create a `slug` from your `id` and `alias`. It's best done in the database like written above.
2. Use the `slug` instead of the `id` to build the URL.
3. When determining the correct `id` to use in a database query (for the single page view), use `(int)$id` to strip the part behind the `':'` and get the real `id`.

Comment: I am new for joomla component development. pls can u explain me step by step how to it. This is my web site url: http://cochrane.qubitwebtechnologies.com/products.html

Comment: this is the issue page, ....................http://cochrane.qubitwebtechnologies.com/products/clearvu-%E2%80%93-the-invisible-wall/1.html

Comment: Thank u very much. just im fix problem.